# Safari selenium Windows Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver

Tags: java, selenium, safari

I have grid node, to launch grid node I have command

Launch grid:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub -port 4441
```

Launch node:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role node -hub http://11.1.1.1:4441/grid/register -port 5541 -browser "browserName=safari, platform=ANY" -Dwebdriver.driver=SafariDriver.safariextz
```

While I run my selenium tests with maven with command:

```
<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dwebdriver.remote.url=http://111.1.1.1:4441/wd/hub -Dwebdriver.driver=safari</argLine>
```

I Get

```
[main] ERROR net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE class org.openqa.selenium
.safari.SafariDriver: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
```

I use serenity and cucumber frameworks to execute my tests. Any Ideas what I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing issues in initiating safari browser on mac machine, and below solution helped me

```
if (browserType.equals("safari")) {
            // System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver", workingDir +
            // "//driver//SafariDriverServer.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.driver",
                    "/driver/SafariDriver.safariextz");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true");
            DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities
                    .safari();
            SafariOptions safariOptions = new SafariOptions();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            safariOptions.getUseCleanSession();
            safariOptions.setUseCleanSession(true);
            desiredCapabilities.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY,
                    safariOptions);

            // deleteCookies();
            driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new SafariDriver());

            ThreadDriver.set(driver);
            // driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 850));
            getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        }
```